# Show duplicated key warning in PHP array definition

Tags: php

Is it possible to get a warning in the following code?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $s = array(
      'a' => '1',
      'a' => '1'
   );

var_export( $s );
```

Comment: i think only way to get warning of updating array value is making function that handles all data assigning, so it can first check if key is used already.

Comment: I'd think the answer is *no*. Not without customizing the PHP parser at least. May be an interesting suggestion for a new `E_STRICT` check for future PHP versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only hope (apart from `count`-ing yourself) is that your editor is smart enough to highlight the typo. This screenshot is from PHPStorm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't really throw an error in this case using standard arrays. However, you can look at extending SPL ArrayObject, and throw errors in it, when you update/redeclare a property.

Update: Something like that:

```
class MyStrictArray extends ArrayObject
{
    public function offsetSet($index, $value)
    {
        if ($this->offsetExists($index)) {
            trigger_error("Can't redeclare a property", E_USER_ERROR);
            return;
        }

        return parent::offsetSet($index, $value);
    }
 }

 // and to use it.
 $array = new MyStrictArray();
 $array['a'] = 'foo';
 $array['a'] = 'bar'; // triggers error
```

Comment: Does `ArrayObject` allow to distinguish between array declaration (where it's an obvious typo) and a legitimate key update?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario if the original question is really only about detecting typos, ArrayObjects won't help. It can only be useful, if you wan't a data structure, where you cannot redeclare properties later in code