# Check for duplicate entries in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any tool I can run PHP code through that would pick up if I typed something like this?

```
$myarray = array(
    'foo' => 'hello',
    'bar' => 'goodbye',
    'foo' => 'hello again' // <= need to pick up the duplicate key on this line
);
```

EDIT: I want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837890/1318194), except not proprietary.

Comment: You're overwritting the value, it's syntactically correct. I don't think such a tool exist.

Comment: Are you parsing already existing code? By default as @MathieuImbert said, first `foo` will be overwritten by second `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your array keys, so PHP would only pickup on the last entry for the key 'foo'

```
$arr = array(
    'foo' => 'hello',
    'bar' => 'goodbye',
    'foo' => 'hello again' // <= need to pick up the duplicate key on this line
);

print_r($arr);
```

returns:

> Array ( [foo] => hello again [bar] => goodbye )

BUT:

```
$arr = array(
    'foo' => 'hello',
    'bar' => 'goodbye',
    'foo3' => 'hello again' // <= need to pick up the duplicate key on this line
);

print_r($arr);
```

returns:

> Array ( [foo] => hello [bar] => goodbye [foo3] => hello again )

even inside a foreach loop (stepping through your array)

```
$arr = array(
    'foo' => 'hello',
    'bar' => 'goodbye',
    'foo' => 'hello again' // <= need to pick up the duplicate key on this line
);

foreach ($arr AS $Keys => $Value)
{
    echo $Keys;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

returns:

```
bar
foo
```

overall moral:

Your array keys are being overwritten, so PHP would recognize no duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do know this, but I'm wondering if I can pick up the fact that I did repeat a key in a long array.

Comment: @DuncanNZ you would have to check for it before entering it into an array

Comment: If your pulling an array which is automatically generated, the keys will be unique, if it's an array you have created on the script, you should know the expected result, and if not. re-check your code for duplicates

Comment: Yes, I am writing the array myself. It is a very long array (~1000 lines of code) so I will need a tool to check for the duplicates.

Comment: unfortunately, the only way is to watch what you are typing, and look over your finished product for duplicate keys. The only duplicates you will beable to pick up on, will be contained within the values. not the keys